# Why doesn't my code change when running it?

Tags: python

I apologize if I am not following a specified format that more experienced users may know. I just started my Python Journey and had a pretty simple question and wanted to get my feet when here for the future.

I started working through "Python Crash Course" and started working on a simple program to take people  from a list and invite them to dinner. The next few steps of this have you use the same list to do a couple other things.

So I used .pop() to pull from the list and print the statement using the name then append that used name to a a new list. Everything seems to work fine when I run it but I was expecting for the actual list in the code to be modified. So if I run it again then the next name is pulled invite and added to the list.

I guess my question is does the code actually change off what you run or is it just the output? From what I see it is just the output. 2nd question is can I actually accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
guests = ['Dennis', 'Mac', 'Charlie', 'Dee', 'Frank']
invited = []

guest_invite = guests.pop()

print(f"{guest_invite.title()} you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.")

print(guests)

invited.append(guest_invite)

print(invited)
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help. Hope I didn't mess this post up to bad.

Comment: Assigning to variables doesn't change the script. It just updates the memory during that run. Every time you run the script it starts fresh.

Comment: If you want to save data between runs, put it in data files.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to display each person in the given list is invited.
To do so I suggest using a range loop which will help us iterate over the invitation list. This is better than using a for loop because we need to mutate the invitation list.
The following will do the trick.

```
guests = ['Dennis', 'Mac', 'Charlie', 'Dee', 'Frank']
invited = []
for guest in range(len(guests)):
    guest_invite = guests[guest]

    print(f"{guest_invite} you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.")
    invited.append(guest_invite)
print(f'All of the following are invited: {invited}')
```

output

```
Dennis you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.
Mac you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.
Charlie you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.
Dee you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.
Frank you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.
All of the following are invited: ['Dennis', 'Mac', 'Charlie', 'Dee', 'Frank']
```

Comment: First I forgot I left the "hell" part in there.... What you recommended is exactly what I was going to work towards. What I was really trying to understand is why is just the output showing that it has been moved into "invited" but the actual code does not change. When I run it I see "Frank: is removed from "guests" and added to "invited" in the output but the code itself still remains guests = ['Dennis', 'Mac', 'Charlie', 'Dee', 'Frank'] invited = []

Comment: Oh right. I did not know you wanted to remove the guests list. But that makes sense. Two options. Would you want the final output just to be an empty guests list? Or would you want it to be more realistic so that the people get removed in guest list one by one?

Comment: I don't think it would be best practice to modify a list that we are iterating on, therefor the realistic approach would not be possible unless we create a copy of `guests` list. IMO we could just empty out guests list at the end of the for range loop @Dubz

Comment: Yes the end product would be an empty guests list. So as the names are used they would be added to the invited list. Then next portion of the project is to "Modify the guest list. So I want to keep building the list through the process. Basically take the person who can come and add them to "notattending" while appending to "guest" then the original process is followed for the new guest.

Comment: Well, I won't do your project for you but. At the end of your for range loop, you can add `guests.clear()`. This will empty out guests. If you have certain guests that won't be coming and you want to keep those guests in `guests` while emptying out attending guests you can try this. `for attending in invited:guests.remove(attending)`. Also say you have an exception for a non attending user, you could do. ` if guests[guest] == 'Mac':continue` in your for range loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think based on feedback on the earlier answer and your initial question what you seem to be looking for is something like this:

```
guests = ['Dennis', 'Mac', 'Charlie', 'Dee', 'Frank']
guest_counter = 0 #Counts number of guests invited

for guest in guests:
    print("Guests Invited: ", guests[:guest_counter]) #Uses string slicing to non-destructively mention already invited guests by moving slicing counter +1
    print(guest, " you are cordially invited to dinner in hell.")
    guest_counter += 1

print("Guests Invited: ", guests[:guest_counter])
```

It uses something called string slicing (google it if you've not yet gotten to that level of proficiency) to non-destructively mention the invitees so you always have your original list for later reference!